# Rails applications layout features to use application_controller in any view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

So I want to have dynamic select boxes for navigation in every view, now they work fine in `localhost:3000` and in `localhost:3000/diys/` but for example in `http://localhost:3000/diys/new` and in `http://localhost:3000/diys/25` they don't.

**Part with select boxes in views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<div class="side_select_box">
    <%= form_tag search_path, :method => :get do %>
        <%= select_tag "side_make_select", options_for_select(@side_makes.collect { |make|[make.make_name, make.id] }), include_blank: "Select make" %>
        <%= select_tag "side_model_select", (render "make_models/make_model") %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**..assets/javascripts/applications.coffee, i think that issue may be on "$.ajax..." line**

```
$ ->
    $(document).on 'change', "#side_make_select", (evt) ->
        $.ajax 'update_side_make_models',
           type: 'GET'
           dataType: 'script'
           data: {
             side_make_id: $("#side_make_select option:selected").val(),
             side_model_div_id: "#side_model_select"
           }
           error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
             console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
           success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
             console.log("Dynamic side make select OK!")
```

**../views/application/update_side_make_models.coffee, issue might be also that this file should be somewhere else, but where?**

```
$("<%= @sidemodelsid %>").empty()
    .append("<%= escape_javascript(render "make_models/make_model") %>")
```

and from there it renders "make_models/make_model" and uses

**application_controller.rb**

```
...
def side_select_boxes
    @side_makes = Make.all
    @models = MakeModel.where("make_id = ?", 0)
end

def update_side_make_models
    @models = MakeModel.where("make_id = ?", params[:side_make_id]).order(:make_model_name)
    @sidemodelsid = params[:side_model_div_id]
end
...
```

So when on homepage or index view I select make in makes select box, it renders models fine, printing this in rails console

```
Started GET "/update_side_make_models?side_make_id=15&side_model_div_id=%23side_model_select&_=1456934054006" for :: 1 at 2016-03-02 17:56:38 +0200                            
Processing by ApplicationController#update_side_make_models as JS                                                   
  Parameters: {"side_make_id"=>"15", "side_model_div_id"=> "#side_model_select", "_"=>"1456934054006"}               
...
```

but in show view and in new view, when i select make in makes select box, nothing happens with models select box, and this is printed in rails console

```
Started GET "/diys/update_side_make_models?side_make_id=15&side_model_div_id=%23side_model_select&_=1456934054008" for ::1 at 2016-03-02 18:01:09 +0200                       
Processing by DiysController#show as JS                   
  Parameters: {"side_make_id"=>"15", "side_model_div_id"=> "#side_model_select", "_"=>"1456934054008", "id"=>"update_side_make_models"}
...
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Diy with 'id'= update_side_make_models):
  app/controllers/diys_controller.rb:128:in `set_diy'
```

So for some reason it puts "/diys/" in front of "/update_side_make_models", and processes it by "DiysController#show", but should process by "ApplicationController#update_side_make_models"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, just needed to point to ajax to go one directory up in

**..assets/javascripts/applications.coffee**

```
$ ->
$(document).on 'change', "#side_make_select", (evt) ->
    $.ajax '../update_side_make_models',
       type: 'GET'
       dataType: 'script'
       data: {
         side_make_id: $("#side_make_select option:selected").val(),
         side_model_div_id: "#side_model_select"
       }
       error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
         console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
       success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
         console.log("Dynamic side make select OK!")
```